# Create an ArcPy script to open a pop up window with some exporting functionality just after running trace tool from utility networks runs successfully

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-pro, excel, utility-network

I am new to ArcPy.

Suppose I ran the Trace Tool from utility network toolset using ArcGIS Pro successfully, and I need to immediately a pop up window comes up with the export functionality to export those results in a Excel created by the Trace tool.  How could I do this?

Comment: You can't, but you could trivially create a wrapper tool that runs the same command, *then* does something afterward.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is a bit vague.  You say "Suppose a geoprocessing tool finished..." but there are literally hundreds of tools and not all of them do something to a dataset, they may actually create a dataset from the inputs.

So, what you are asking is not sensible.  That said, if your workflow was always to add a new field, calculate a new value and it's at that point you want to do your export then consider using ModelBuilder. You can even develop your model into a *model tool* so it looks like a single tool you are running. Explore the help file on the topic of ModelBuilder.

Comment: Okay sure , Sorry for that . I ran the trace tool(utility network tool ) from arcgis pro and the output which i got i want that in excel , so is there a way i can get that sir.

Comment: run the Table to Excel tool on the output. Alternatively create a Python Script/ArcTool (or modelbuilder) to combine both processes, the trace and excel export.